# After downloading from playstore, app crashes when started

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, crash, google-play

I recently uploaded an app into google play store and everything was working fine. I downloaded it and was able to register a new user. The app crashes while loading the main activity of the app.

**This is the stacktrace that I got:**

```
2020-09-10 10:34:58.686 2801-5301/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting period=20000 preferred_charging_state=1 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService required_network_type=0 runtime=1599723298662 required_idleness_state=0 source=16 service_kind=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms persistence_level=1 source_version=203019000 last_runtime=0 user_id=0 job_id=-1 requires_charging=0 tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG flex_time=9000 task_type=0 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}}
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:783)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1548)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
    at arkc.a(:com.google.android.gms@203019020@20.30.19 (040406-326531024):122)
    at ariz.a(:com.google.android.gms@203019020@20.30.19 (040406-326531024):183)
    at ariz.a(:com.google.android.gms@203019020@20.30.19 (040406-326531024):22)
    at ariz.a(:com.google.android.gms@203019020@20.30.19 (040406-326531024):178)
    at arfc.run(:com.google.android.gms@203019020@20.30.19 (040406-326531024):9)
    at suq.b(:com.google.android.gms@203019020@20.30.19 (040406-326531024):12)
    at suq.run(:com.google.android.gms@203019020@20.30.19 (040406-326531024):8)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at tas.run(:com.google.android.gms@203019020@20.30.19 (040406-326531024):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This question may have been asked before, but I have researched all over and I could not find the solution to this problem. Any help will be appreciated. The app has been created using android java and firebase.

Answer (score 0):

it's a Firebase  or  pro guard rule error you can easily try to stop Firebase Crashlytics if the proplem gone try to Download the latest config file (google-services.json) from the firebase console [Project Settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general) and update in your project. It should fix the issue.

if it dose not help try to stop pro guard rule if the crash fixed then change the rule of it

if the Proguard rules was not the problem
try to find a good combination of rules to keep both Firebase and Proguard alive at the same time.

Comment: Hello, do I disable the crashlytics from Firebase? Or at the Manifest?